# Donut tutorial icing, the vertices are inside the donut and I can't see what I'm moving

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]

I'm doing the donut tutorial, but for the icing the vertices are inside the donut and I can't see what I'm moving.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220616/stuck-at-the-part-5-level-1-sculpting-where-andrew-works-on-the-fixing-the

Comment: Search this site for “donut”, or even “donut icing inside”. If you find that the problem you are encountering has never before been experienced, I’ll eat a brick of ramen noodles raw.

Comment: Enable the Snap To face option to make sure that it doesn't penetrate the donut, but keep in mind that even with the icing snapping it may look like it penetrates because the donut seems to have a Subdivision Surface modifier which makes its surface looks rounder than it really is